# How to get values from bootstrap card and stored in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get values from 2 card and store in array using jquery. i want Store card value like this given below using dynamic way.

> array(
>       card_1{
>               a:'AAA',
>               b:'BE',
>               c:'ECE',
>               d:'June 1994',
>               e:'Pursuing',
>               f:'Full-Time',
>               g:'AAAA',
>               h:'BBBB',
>               i:'//placehold.it/115'
>       },
>       card_2{
>               a:'BBB',
>               b:'BE',
>               c:'CSE',
>               d:'June 2000',
>               e:'May 2010',
>               f:'Part-Time',
>               g:'DDDD',
>               h:'CCCC',
>               i:'//placehold.it/115'
>       },
>   )

```html
<div class="content with-padding col-sm-12 no-border education">
  <div class="card flex-row flex-wrap border-bottom m-3 " style="border:none;">
    <div class="card-header no-border p-0">
      <img src="//placehold.it/115" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="card-block col-sm-10 no-border p-2">
      <h5 class="card-title m-0 p-0">AAA</h5>
      <p class="card-text m-0 p-0">BE-<span>ECE</span></p>
      <p class="card-text m-0 p-0">June 1994 - Pursuing. <span>Full-Time</span></p>
      <p class="card-text m-0 p-0">AAAA,BBBB</p>
    </div>
    <div>

      <button class="float-right rounded-circle  education-remove ripple-effect "><i class="icon-material-outline-delete text-danger ml-2"></i></button>
      <button class="float-right rounded-circle   ripple-effect "><i class="icon-feather-edit "></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card flex-row flex-wrap border-bottom m-3 " style="border:none;">
    <div class="card-header no-border p-0">
      <img src="//placehold.it/115" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="card-block col-sm-10 no-border p-2">
      <h5 class="card-title m-0 p-0">BBB</h5>
      <p class="card-text m-0 p-0">BE-<span>CSE</span></p>
      <p class="card-text m-0 p-0">June 2000 - May 2010. <span>Part-Time</span></p>
      <p class="card-text m-0 p-0">DDDD,CCCC</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="float-right rounded-circle  education-remove ripple-effect "><i class="icon-material-outline-delete text-danger ml-2"></i></button>
      <button class="float-right rounded-circle   ripple-effect "><i class="icon-feather-edit "></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to iterate through each `card-block` and access the card-block's `card-title` and again iterate through the card-block's inner `card-text` children and get their text nodes. You could use the following example to get the values of these text nodes and then you would need to use regex to filter the values for your json string

```
$(function()
{
    $('.card-block').each((index, value) =>
    {
        var title = $(value).find('.card-title').text();
        console.log(title);

        $(value).find('.card-text').each((textIndex, textValue) =>
        {
           var cardtext = $(textValue).text();
           console.log(cardtext);
      });
  });
});
```